# How to install Loki+Promtail to forward K8S pod logs to Grafana Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, grafana-loki, promtail

I am still new to K8S infrastructure but I am trying to convert VM infrastructure to K8S on GCP/GKE and I am stuck at forwarding the logs properly after getting Prometheus metrics forwarded correctly. I am also trying to do this without helm, to better understand K8S.

The logs of the loki pod, look as expected when comparing to a docker format in a VM setup.
But I do not know how to start the promtail service without a port, since in a docker format promtail does not have to expose a port. I get the following error:

> The Service "promtail" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value

My configuration files look like:
`loki-config.yml`

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

ingester:
  wal:
    enabled: true
    dir: /tmp/wal
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 1h       # Any chunk not receiving new logs in this time will be flushed
  max_chunk_age: 1h           # All chunks will be flushed when they hit this age, default is 1h
  chunk_target_size: 1048576  # Loki will attempt to build chunks up to 1.5MB, flushing first if chunk_idle_period or max_chunk_age is reached first
  chunk_retain_period: 30s    # Must be greater than index read cache TTL if using an index cache (Default index read cache TTL is 5m)
  max_transfer_retries: 0     # Chunk transfers disabled

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

storage_config:
  boltdb_shipper:
    active_index_directory: /tmp/loki/boltdb-shipper-active
    cache_location: /tmp/loki/boltdb-shipper-cache
    cache_ttl: 24h         # Can be increased for faster performance over longer query periods, uses more disk space
    shared_store: filesystem
  filesystem:
    directory: /tmp/loki/chunks

compactor:
  working_directory: /tmp/loki/boltdb-shipper-compactor
  shared_store: filesystem

limits_config:
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h
  ingestion_burst_size_mb: 16
  ingestion_rate_mb: 16
chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: false
  retention_period: 0s

ruler:
  storage:
    type: local
    local:
      directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  rule_path: /tmp/loki/rules-temp
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory
  enable_api: true
```

`promtail-config.yml`

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

# this is the place where promtail will store the progress about how far it has read the logs
positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

# address of loki server to which promtail should push the logs
clients:
  - url: https://999999:...=@logs-prod3.grafana.net/api/prom/push
# which logs to read/scrape
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: system
    static_configs:
    - targets:
        - localhost
      labels:
        job: varlogs
        __path__: /var/log/*log
  - job_name: node
    static_configs:
    - targets:
        - localhost
      labels:
        job: node  # label-1
        host: localhost    # label-2
        __path__: /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*log
```

Then the deployment files:
`loki-deploy.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: loki
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: loki
      network: cluster-1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: loki
        network: cluster-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: loki
          image:  grafana/loki
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3100
          volumeMounts:
            - name: loki-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/loki/loki.yml
              subPath: loki.yml
      volumes:
        - name: loki-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: "loki-config"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: loki
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: loki
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: loki
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3100
```

And finally `promtail-deploy.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: promtail
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: promtail
      network: cluster-1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: promtail
        network: cluster-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: promtail
          image:  grafana/promtail
          volumeMounts:
            - name: promtail-config-volume
              mountPath: /mnt/config/promtail-config.yml
              subPath: promtail.yml
      volumes:
        - name: promtail-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: "promtail-config"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: promtail
  namespace: monitoring
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're describing is answered exactly by the error message.

Your second Kubernetes Service manifest, named `promtail`, does not have any specification. For services, at least `spec.ports` is required. You should add a label selector as well, so the Service can pick up the Deployment's pods properly.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: promtail
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: promtail
  ports:
    - port: <ServicePort>
      targetPort: <PodPort>
```

However, if you do not need to communicate with the Promtail pods from external services, then simply skip creating the Service itself.

May I add, if you need to expose these logs to a service running outside of your cluster, such as Grafana Cloud, you should create a Service of `LoadBalancer` type for Loki instead. This will request a public IP for it, making it accessible worldwide - assuming your Kubernetes cluster is managed by some cloud provider.

Making Loki public is insecure, but a good first step towards consuming these logs externally.